# How can I access my method from another class

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c#, I started a few days ago, so please excuse me if it is basic.
I have two forms, the first one is like a login page, where someone enters their name. On my "Info.cs" class, it reads this name via a setter, into a variable, and my Getter called "GetCardName" returns this Name. I now made a new form where I want to access this name via the GetCardName getter, just dont know how too. Heres the code :

Here is some of the "info.cs" class code:

```
private string CardName { get; set; } = "";
   
public string GetCardName()
{
    return this.CardName;
}

public void SetName(string name = "")
{
    this.CardName = name;
}
```

And here is the code from the other form that is just trying to call `GetCardName()`:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblWelcome.Text = Info.GetCardName();
}
```

Comment: For reference, I have used breaks in the code to check if the Name is actually being set in the GetCardName method, and it is, I just dont know how to call this method from another class just yet

Comment: You can [edit] your question rather then commenting it.

Comment: You need an instance of the `Info` class created in your form somewhere. So, e.g. `Info myInfo = new Info();` then `e.g. myInfo.SetName("Yes");`, and then you can do the `lblWelcome.Text = myInfo.GetCardName()` part.

Comment: ^^ ... which is actually superfluent, because `CardGame` is already a public _property_. Which means it already _has_ a setter function "under the hood". See [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: You're writing Java in C#. In C#, there's specific syntax for properties, rather than using a naming convention on methods.

Comment: When i Do this, it like, overwrites whatever was already saved in the GetCardName method from the Info.cs class

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't "save" anyting in a method. Neither do you in a class. A class is just a template, a "plan" of something. You need a concrete instance with fields (which properties are backed by) to "save" aynthing.

Comment: The GetCardName returns the variable CardName. If i create a new instance of it on the other form, it clears whatever is in CardName

Comment: No. It is just a different instance. You have a plan of a drawer. Now you build one drawer and put somethng in it. Then you build another drawer somewhere else. Do you expect that second drawer to contain anything?

Comment: I'm doing it right now. If i create the new instance, it doesn't output anything. I'm using breaks to check, if i don't create a new instance, the name saves perfectly in the variable. If i do, nothing is there

Comment: If do not create an instance you cannot save anything. Except there is some "static" stuff going on at the same time. Do you happen to use "static" anywhere? You sure do not in the example in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating `Form2` you need also pass it reference to the other form to get its properties.

So when creating and showing `Form1` you should also create `Form2` to pass that reference. Example (not tested) code:

```
var form1 = new Form1();
var form2 = new Form2(form1);
form1.Show();
```

and `Form2` should be like:

```
public class Form2
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        _form1 = form1;
        // ... other initialization code
    }
    
    // ... other class declarations
}
```

General solution is: you need to **persist** reference to the `Form1` being shown to the user and then pass that reference to `Form2` whenever you create it.

Comment: Which creates a hard dependency between Form1 and Form2. Do you really want to suggest this?

Comment: @Fildor Yes. I think introducing interfaces and design patterns (loose coupling, dependency injection) here would drift away from the core problem. Moreover, this would be base solution, which OP can then improve on his own.

Comment: I don't know. I have a bad feeling about this.

Comment: @Fildor To properly solve this problem, I should introduce view model for each form, explain how they view models would communicate, also explain what is view model and how to apply MVVM or other MV* pattern. I think then answer would become very big and off-topic

Comment: Yes, I know. Maybe we should abstract from `Form`. I am under the impression OP's misconception goes way deeper than the handling of Form properties / fields in particular. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I started about 2 days ago so i'm very new, but I appreciate the help

Comment: @AlexGottschalk The problem we have is right now, that a "proper" and exhaustive answer would be waaaay too long for this format.

Comment: My buddy who is very good at this language is going to help me later, just wanted to see if I could figure it out myself with your help

Answer (score 0):

You have two options :

- you can create an instance of the class that you want to call
  EX : `Info infoVar = new Info();` (now you can use infoVar to call any methods of the Info.cs class)
- you can make Info class a STATIC class (probably not what you want to do, but still helpful for the future perhaps) This makes it possible to call the info class directly without having to create a variable of that class but has some drawbacks. (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members))

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to achieve what you want:

**Public static property**:

```
public class Info
{
    public static string CardName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

You can access it or set value to it directly by:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set
    Info.CardName = "Some name"; 
    // Get
    lblWelcome.Text = Info.CardName;
}
```

**Public non-static property**:

```
public class Info
{
    public string CardName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

You can access it or set value to it directly too, but need to create `Info` class instance before:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Info info = new Info();
    // Set
    info.CardName = "Some name"; 
    // Get
    lblWelcome.Text = info.CardName;
}
```

**Private static field with separated public static Get and Set methods**:

```
public class Info
{
    private static string cardName = string.Empty;

    public static string GetCardName()
    {
        return cardName;
    }

    public static void SetCardName(string name = "")
    {
        cardName = name;
    }
}
```

You can access `GetCardName` and `SetCardName` without creating `Info` class instance:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set
    Info.SetCardName("Some name"); 
    // Get
    lblWelcome.Text = Info.GetCardName();
}
```

**Private non-static field with separated public non-static Get and Set methods**:

```
public class Info
{
    private string cardName = string.Empty;

    public string GetCardName()
    {
        return cardName;
    }

    public void SetCardName(string name = "")
    {
        cardName = name;
    }
}
```

You can access `GetCardName` and `SetCardName` after creating `Info` class instance:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Info info = new Info();
    // Set
    info.SetCardName("Some name"); 
    // Get
    lblWelcome.Text = info.GetCardName();
}
```

Difference between fields and properties was pretty nice explained here: [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property). In short, properties are "wrappers" over fields, which usually are `private` and you can't access to them directly or modify. It is a part of [Member Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Also properties allow to add some validations through property setter to be sure that valid value is stored at `cardName` field, e.g.:

```
public class Info
{
    private string cardName = string.Empty;
    public string CardName
    {
        get => cardName;
        set 
        {
            // Check that value you trying to set isn't null
            if (value != null)
                cardName = value;
            // Or check that name is not too short
            if (value.Length >= 3) // Card name should be at least of 3 characters
                cardName = value;              
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info myInfo=new info();
lblWelcome.Text = myInfo.GetCardName();
```